# how to let tor change ip automatically?

Tags: proxy, tor

After i click the "Use a New Identify" button on Vidalia, i will get a new proxy ip. 
Can tor change ip automatically?

My program needs random proxies, so the server will not block the connection.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You could modify "**/etc/tor/torrc**" or in "path/to/your/torbrowser/**Data/Tor/torrc**" to cycle proxies faster:

```
MaxCircuitDirtiness NUM
```

Feel free to reuse a circuit that was first used at most NUM seconds ago, but never attach a new stream to a circuit that is too old.  (Default: 10 minutes)

Comment: PS - I think the minimum for this is 10 seconds. If you use a lower value, tor will probably default to 10 sec anyways. FYI.

Comment: @Nimo true, But at my tips, I success get less then 10 sec by `service tor restart` between each `torsocks` command (restart tor service make new ip) :-D

Answer (score 7):

Tor creates new circuits on its own every ten minutes. Note that a new circuit does not necessarily mean a new IP, for more information see [stem's faq entry on this](https://stem.torproject.org/faq.html#how-do-i-request-a-new-identity-from-tor).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced that Tor does not update ip for some sites (like [vk.com](https://vk.com)) even when you set the `MaxCircuitDirtiness`. I dunno if it is some headers they send or if they just pay Tor developers for that =D.

To get around that there was a "New Tor Circuit for this Site" button in [older Tor versions (6.5.1)](https://askubuntu.com/a/515148/306771) with a *Ctrl+Shift+L* shortcut. What I did was opening a page of the web site and triggering the *Ctrl+Shift+L* key combiation every minute using [xdotool](https://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) terminal app:

```
while true; do 
    xdotool keydown ctrl; 
    xdotool keydown shift; 
    xdotool key l; 
    xdotool keyup ctrl; 
    xdotool keyup shift; 
    sleep 60; 
done
```

The only downside is that you have to keep this window opened and focused the whole time =3.