# tor does not honor MaxCircuitDirtiness

Tags: ip, ip-address, tor, tor-browser-bundle

I am having a strange behaviour when using tor, it does not take into account the `MaxCircuitDirtiness` I have set in the configuration at `Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Tor\torrc`... nor the default value that is supposed to be 10 minutes.

I use https://ipecho.net/plain to check my IP but it doesn't seem to change at the given time.

Ex: MaxCircuitDirtiness 11 should change IP every 11 seconds

Answer (score 1):

kaur,

Please note that `MaxCircuitDirtiness` only ensures that **a new Tor circuit** is created and used, but that **does not always imply a new IP** (i.e. does not always imply a different "end node" on the new circuit).

You can read more [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17132573/10440588), for example.